# submit TWS schedule on specific AGENT

Tags: workload-scheduler, tws, tivoli-work-scheduler

is this possible to submit TWS schedule or run TWS schedule on specific AGENT

e.g currently TWS dynamically  select AGENT [AGENT A] and run jobs, how can we specifically select AGENT [AGENT B] and run schedule job on that

Answer (score 0):

This is not a native scenario, but you can look at a some different ways to address that.
Schedule workstation is not relevant, what you need to change is the job workstation only.

You can use:

1. Rest APIs

   - Run a query on job stream definition to get the id: `POST /model/jobstream/header/query`
   - Generate a new temporary instance for the job stream: `POST /plan/current/jobstream/{jobstreamId}/action/make_jobstream`
   - Modify the returned JSON replacing the job workstations
   - Submit the modified instance: `POST /plan/{planId}/jobstream/action/submit_jobstream`
2. Use pools
   If you actually want to move all jobs from one agent to another, you can use pools workstations and change the actual agents in the pool: changing members for static pools, or moving a logical resource for dynamic pools
3. Clone the definition
   Another option is to clone the definition with composer or using workload application templates and then submit the cloned definition. If you want you can remove the cloned definition after the submission.